System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'Response status code does not indicate success: 411 (Length Required).'
I am getting this error:

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 411 (Length Required).

while doing a HTTP POST request.
My POST call looks like this - any ideas/suggestions?
public async Task<MyResponse?> MyMethodAsync(MyRequest request, string url, string accessToken)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();

    var requestJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);

    var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), url);
    httpRequest.Content = new StringContent(requestJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    httpRequest.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");
    //httpRequest.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Length", requestJson.Length.ToString()); //Adding this didn't help

    var response = await client.SendAsync(httpRequest);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyResponse>(result);
}

I also tried to use the PostAsync as well - with the same result.
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "application/json");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Length", requestJson.Length.ToString());
var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);


Have you tried creating the content as a variable and setting its content length directly - var content = new StringContent(requestJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"); - then content.Headers.ContentLength = requestJson.Length; and then httpRequest.Content = content; ?  (Or possibly Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(requestJson) instead of requestJson.Length, depending on the content, as the specified length should be the number of bytes, not characters.)

Could you please check what does the following code says after you set the request's body: request.Content.Headers.ContentLength ?

@NeilT: It made no difference. Both continue throwing the 411 error

@PeterCsala: It showed 92

Could you please try the following: var content = new StringContent(requestJson, Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeNames.Application.Json); and then var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

@PeterCsala: I ended up using RestSharp. Sorry, I didn't see this message on time..

No worries, if it works for you then that's fine :)

I ended up using RestSharp and below is what I have:
public class MyClient
{
    private readonly IRestClient _restClient;
    public MyClient(string apiUrl, string token)
    {
        _restClient = new RestClient(apiUrl);
        _restClient.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
    }

    public async Task<MyResponse?> MyMethodAsync(MyRequest request, string url)
    {
        var restRequest = new RestRequest(url);
        restRequest.AddBody(request);

        var response = await _restClient.ExecutePostAsync(restRequest);
        if (response is { IsSuccessful: true, Content: not null })
        {
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyResponse>(response.Content);
        }

        return (MyResponse?) null;
    }
}

